# How to automatazie the printing frame

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automatize a task at my company and at a point, I must print it to PDF and save it as a file.

When I finally get to the point where this frame pop's up, the selenium isn't working anymore. I've tried `driver.forward()`, but no success.

Sure I am missing something but I am unsure what it is.

[image: print area image]

When I tried `driver.forward()`, I expected the selenium to acknowledge I was moving out of the parent page.

I also wrote the frame codes but also had no success.

Answer (score 2):

This is because Selenium is a webdriver which meant to drive web pages and web elements instead of controlling web browser itself. Hence, when it comes to popout, dialog or certain browsers interactivity, it may no longer works.

For your use case, I suggest using existing Python package such as [PDFKit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/0.4.1/) to convert a webpage to PDF directly.

If due to some technical specs, where you have to invoke Print-to-PDF manually. You need to consider the use of [ActionChains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) or some cross-platform interaction package such as [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Here's a quick sample of how you can do it with `PyAutoGui`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

url = 'https://www.google.com'

with driver as driver:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)

    # Delay to Load Site
    time.sleep(5)

    # Invoke Print
    driver.execute_script("window.print();")
    time.sleep(2)

    file_name = 'TEST.PDF'
    FILE_PATH = f'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\{file_name}'

    pyautogui.typewrite(FILE_PATH)
    pyautogui.click(1283, 634)

    # Delay for PDF Download to Complete
    time.sleep(5)
```

Take note that if you are using `PyAutoGUI` approach, you need to invoke the cursor with respective x-coordinate and y-coordinate properly, and they will be different on different screen size, settings etc